# Behavior of "round" function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

Could anyone explain me this pice of code:

```
>>> round(0.45, 1)
0.5
>>> round(1.45, 1)
1.4
>>> round(2.45, 1)
2.5
>>> round(3.45, 1)
3.5
>>> round(4.45, 1)
4.5
>>> round(5.45, 1)
5.5
>>> round(6.45, 1)
6.5
>>> round(7.45, 1)
7.5
>>> round(8.45, 1)
8.4
>>> round(9.45, 1)
9.4
```

**Updated**

I guess it is because of floating representation. Am I right?

Comment: Same phenomenon in 2.7.2

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10093820/1258041

Comment: @SperanskyDanil You're right, sorry, this is not the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right. None of the numbers can be represented exactly. In some cases the fractional part is strictly greater than `0.45` and in some it is strictly less:

```
In [4]: ['%.20f' % val for val in (0.45, 1.45, 2.45, 3.45, 4.45, 5.45, 6.45, 7.45, 8.45, 9.45)]
Out[4]: 
['0.45000000000000001110',
 '1.44999999999999995559',
 '2.45000000000000017764',
 '3.45000000000000017764',
 '4.45000000000000017764',
 '5.45000000000000017764',
 '6.45000000000000017764',
 '7.45000000000000017764',
 '8.44999999999999928946',
 '9.44999999999999928946']
```

This explains the seemingly inconsistent rounding.

Answer (score 0):

as NPE said the binary representation of a decimal number is not exact,so you can get strange behaviour from rounding ,a module that solves this problem is decimal,
[Here is the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal.html)