# Strange behaviour of np.rint function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Minimal code:

```
import numpy as np

np.rint(0.5)   # Output is 0     OK!
np.rint(718.5) # Output is 718   OK!
np.rint(719.5) # Output is 720   WRONG!
```

Obviously the expected result for the last row would be 719. Any explanation?

I am running NumPy 1.19.5 and Python 3.9.1

Comment: I believe this has been a thing since forever, See, for example [this](http://lukewrites.com/posts/rounding-decimals-in-python-or-why-doesnt-5-round-to-1/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093783/rounding-error-in-python-with-non-odd-number/10093820#10093820) .

Comment: Thanks, found the Banker's rule I wasn't aware of. Problem is, as I'm working with 720p images, it causes an IndexingError as row 720 does not exist...